# Ajax return full structure html not only data of particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi i am using ajax to reload the div content without reloading the whole page for that i am using following code

```
$.post(window.location,{llrating:ratingvalue},function(){
        //alert("Thanks for rating");
        //location.reload();
        $(".header-search").load(location.href + " .header-search");

    });
```

Now it works fine but it duplicates the whole content e.g if i want to refresh my div

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

then it refresh the div but the result comes in this way

```
    <div class="content"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

Hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Comment: I think you need `$(".header-search .content").load(location.href + " .header-search .content");`

Comment: i have tried this but again my issue is it is reloading and duplicate the div as i give the example in my question above

Comment: you can take a look at [link](http://www.dev.ludhianalive.com/Zem_Music_company-11927)

Comment: lol don't ajax the whole page just for a rating value, ajax only the rating value

Comment: i know bro i did that too but it is insert the div inside same div

Answer (score 1):

When you use fragment loading

> $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" ); 
>   When this method
>   executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html, but then jQuery
>   parses the returned document to find the element with an ID of
>   container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted into the
>   element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved document
>   is discarded.

So load the `content` element to `header-search`

```
$(".header-search").load(location.href + " .header-search .content");
```